# USB Image transfer Linux

Tags: usb

In my project I want to receive/send images to a USB device gadget. For this  host side USB driver needs to be written. According to my understanding an image file cannot be directly transferred by reading and storing the bytes one by one till we encounter an EOF(as is done in a normal text file). So how do we do it?

I got a relevant topic on this at the following link:
[What is most appropriate USB class to handle images and video transfer and streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096942/what-is-most-appropriate-usb-class-to-handle-images-and-video-transfer-and-strea)

but still things were not clear. Should I use libptp with libusb to transfer the image files? i could not get any sample/example code which could explain if its possible or how its done. Thanks for the help in advance!

Regards,
Shweta

Also, from some more investigation, i think LibMTP can be used for image transfer. But to eork for that i guess we need LibUSB aslo installed. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) if you are familiar with python and pygame. Also you can convert image to string and transfer it to other device by pyusb package in python.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But i have never worked with python. :( Also, i cannot use it as i have to work in C only...